# Updating Date in date object with time object in javasrcript

Tags: javascript, date, time

**I am trying to update date object with time object**

**From `new Date()` in javascript I am getting the date object. For example `Tue Nov 06 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`**

**From input type = time, I am getting time object. For example `Thu Jan 01 1970 16:52:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`**

**Now I need to join this two as follow**

```
Tue Nov 06 2018 16:52:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

**Are there any way to do this. Bassically I need to replace the time in date object **

Comment: you will get both if you have tried `var d = new Date(); alert(d)` it will get the date and time with timestamp and timezone. See here https://jsbin.com/xibizotede/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Please do not put everything in bold, it will not get you faster or better responses. It's just annoying.

Comment: I am using separate input field to get time. So in that case I was unable to do that @ChintuYadavSara

Comment: I will @RobG. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: @sd_dewasurendra please paste what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this by **just** using `setHours()` and `setMinutes()` methods.

See an example below,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a date after changing the hours.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setHours(16);
    d.setMinutes(52);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'd agree with with what @Jay Surya is saying, you must use a library for date manipulation exercises, otherwise you will find all sorts of problems when it comes to multi browser environment.

I'd recommend [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) for date related manipulations. Using MomentJS you can do the same like this,

```
moment().hours(16);
moment().minutes(52);
```

and guaranteed to be supporting in most of the [major browsers](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/),

> Chrome on Windows XP, IE 8, 9, and 10 on Windows 7, IE 11 on Windows
>   10, latest Firefox on Linux, and latest Safari on OSX 10.8 and 10.11.

Hope this help,

Cheers.

Comment: @sd_dewasurendra You are welcome. I am pleased to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set time with setTime() method on date object. But setTime() takes timestamp. So Instead you can split the time value coming from the input and use setHours() and setMinutes() seperately.

```
//new date object
var d = new Date();
var time = input.value()//"11:41"
var hrs = time.split(':')[0]
var mins = time.split(':')[1]
//set time
d.setHours(hrs);
d.setMinutes(mins);
```

Btw, input type-date is not widely supported across browsers, hence you may want to use some datepicker libraries.

Answer (score 1):

This is how we do it ;-)

> The method .setHours() takes 1 required parameter and up to 3
>   optional parameters ( minutes, seconds, milliseconds ).

```
date.setHours( hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds );
```

> Note you need to make sure your timing object is an instance of Date Object, you can do so with the `instanceof operator`

```
if ( time instanceof Date ) true;
```

> Note if you overwrite the range of any of these parameters javascript
>   will correct the behaviour..

```
var date = new Date( '11-06-2018' );
// Tue Nov 06 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
date.setHours( 25 );
// Wed Nov 07 2018 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

```js
//setup

var date = new Date( '11-06-2018' );
// Tue Nov 06 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

var time = new Date(0); time.setHours(10,14);
// Thu Jan 01 1970 10:14:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

date.setHours( time.getHours(), time.getMinutes(), time.getSeconds() );
// Tue Nov 06 2018 10:14:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

console.log(date);
```

Comment: @sd_dewasurendra No problem we are here to help each other  :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var date = new Date()


var time = new Date(0); time.setHours(16,52);

date.setHours( time.getHours(), time.getMinutes(), time.getSeconds() );
console.log(date)
```